# formula to calculate axis values

Tags: math

Let's say I have a simple line chart with 5 values (a = 155, b = 200, c = 250, d = 300, e 0 345)

I need a way to calculate which values go on the Y-axis, in such a way that the values look nice. I also want to see the minor steps.

If I use a simple formula I would do this:

MaxValue - Minvalue = difference
345 - 155 = 190

For 5 steps:
190 / 4 = 47.50 per step

Thet would lead to these values for the Y-axis:

Y0 = 155

Y1 = 203

Y2 = 250

Y3 = 298

Y4 = 345

What I actually would like is the values to be:

Y0 = 150

Y1 = 200

Y2 = 250

Y3 = 300

Y4 = 350

But how do I calculate this?

Before calculation I don't know the magnitude of the values, it could be also like thousands, or tens.

I hope I did explain it ok. English is not my main language, so please ask if things are not clear.

Comment: Is this question about generating values to display next to the axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you are speaking about fitting your points to a line. This a non trivial problem (but still simple) called [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression). The traditional algorithm used to solve it is the [least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) algorithm. I am quite sure that in all language you can find a library where it is implemented.

[Edit] Wolfram alpha can do the job : 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=linear+fit+155+200+250+300+345

Comment: Yeah, this looks like it. And I think I can find a few examples for C# too.

Comment: @Thomas - I must say that you question was confusing in its intent. Kudos to @Antonin for getting that!

Answer (score 0):

Rounding is the key here. You can round your extreme values to 1st digit, 2nd digit, etc. and use the rounded values as your axis limits.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to write a simple "coin-rounding" algorithm. This is an algorithm that rounds a number (eg. your proposed step) so that it begins with either 1,2 or 5. For example 47.50 would get coin-rounded to 50.

Comment: That works good for the example I've given. But if the values become 145, 200, 250, 300, 345 the difference is exactly 200, which gives a step of 50. If I want to start my axis at 100, then I won't come to 350 in 5 steps. So that's second part of the problem.

Comment: @Thomas: I have no idea what you are talking about.